# C++ ifstream appending garbage data while reading from a text file

Tags: c++, ifstream

```
char* readFromFile(char* location)
{
    int total = 0;
    ifstream ifile = ifstream(location);
    ifile.seekg(0, ifile.end);
    total = ifile.tellg();

    cout << "Total count" << total << endl;
    char* file = new char[total+1];

    ifile.seekg(0, ifile.beg);

    ifile.read(file, total+1);

    cout <<"File output" << endl<< file << "Output end"<<endl;

    return file;
}
```

here it is printing the file data but it also appending some garbage value. how should I fix it?

Comment: Null terminate your string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`read` just reads a number of bytes, it doesn't null terminate the sequence. While `cout` expects a null terminated sequence, so it continues to print random memory that is located after your array until it runs into a 0. So you need to allocate one extra character, and then fill it with a null character.

```
char* readFromFile(char* location)
{
    int total = 0;
    ifstream ifile = ifstream(location);
    ifile.seekg(0, ifile.end);
    total = ifile.tellg();

    cout << "Total count" << total << endl;
    char* file = new char[total+1];

    ifile.seekg(0, ifile.beg);

    ifile.read(file, total); //don't need the +1 here

    file[total] = '\0'; //Add this

    cout <<"File output" << endl<< file << "Output end"<<endl;

    return file; 
}
```

Comment: It is still padding the string by -51 ascii value. can you tell whats wrong?

Comment: @fallenAngel, I'd start off by using a hex editor to examine your file. Make sure the data is correct. Then if that is correct, double check all your variables and the use of them. After that I'd set a break point and step through your code and double check that you have done the right thing at every step.

Comment: I have already checked in hex editor, which is showing ok. (Update) If i pass binary flag it is working ok.

Comment: @fallenAngel, that is weird. Does your file end with a newline character and which operating system are you using? Binary flag should only change the treatment of newline characters as far as I know, but I suppose there could be other translations happening.